# What are the supported versions of RHEL 5 by the NSA?

Tags: attacks

I have read through the document found at,

[NSA RHEL5 Security Requirements](http://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/os/redhat/NSA_RHEL_5_GUIDE_v4.2.pdf)

In reading through the document, it seems that you can use any version of RHEL 5 as long as it supports the requirements in the document. Is there any other document out there that says that RHEL 5.3 is the only supported version of RHEL 5 by the NSA? If so links to the document would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean if it's passing all security clearances, then yes RHEL5 is the only government approved version, RHEL 6 might still not have all of them as required by U.S. government, however it can be used in business no problem, as it's kernel it's pretty much stable as it seems.

Comment: And this is pretty much generic guide how to setup linux in a way it's not completely naive.

Answer (score 2):

This page at RedHat's site seem to have the most current information available on public sites and suggests a RHEL6 standard may be available in November 2012:

http://www.redhat.com/solutions/industry/government/certifications.html#Require

As far as I can tell from the STIG itself at the linked site, the version of RH5 is not relevant to the requirement:

http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/os/unix/red_hat.html